# web app on mobiles with phonegap

Tags: javascript, web-applications, cordova, background-process

I have a web application (chat room) in html + javascript that basically sends requests to the server every 5 seconds to check for new messages.

It already works on mobile but there are 2 main problems:

- it does not beep (it works on pc) with new messages
- when the browser is put on background, the javascript obviously stops being executed, therefore the connection to the server is lost and the client disconnected.

i was thinking of using phonegap not only to make it cross-platform but also to fix those problems stated above. would they be resolved with the use of phonegap?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

phoneGap doesn't support custom push notification. it basically open a browser and expose you some native support via [API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/index.html).
in order to do some native actions like push notifications and/or sound playing i suggest you check out some of the **[plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins)** options available or even write your own for that.

Comment: yea all i'd like it to do is to keep the js running even if the app is in background. is that achiveable?

Comment: not while you are on the browser (PhoneGap just pops put the browser). you'll have to do some native code for that. and to do that look on the plugin options i listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Playing sounds can be done easily using the [Media API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media). As for having the JavaScript run in the background it really depends on the OS. On Android the JS will continue to run if you leave the app via the home button but the back button kills the app so you would stop the JS. It is probably better to write a service that always runs in that case.

Alternatively you'd look at a push type solution to notify you of new messages.